# How to generate a dynamic amount of nested editables in a CKEditor widget-plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am building a widget-plugin for my instance of CKEditor `{version: "4.4.5", revision: "2bc6924"}` to display a dynamic number of tabs.

I am having troubles setting up a **dynamic** range of *nested editables*.

First off I followed the instructions on http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1 to build a widget.

I then found out about the limitations of defining editables and followed the instructions on this page http://ckeditor.com/comment/135051#comment-135051 to accomplish my goal.

Basically it's this piece of code that describes the editables:

```
// defined somewhere in init function of the widget:
var maxItems = 4;
function _editables() {
    var editables = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
        editables['title-' + i] = {
            selector: '.ed-title-' + i,
            allowedContent: 'br em strong'
        };
        editables['content-' + i] = {
            selector: '.ed-content-' + i,
            allowedContent: '*'
        };
    }
    return editables;
}


// defined in the plugin config:
editables: _editables(_num_items),
```

Initially this works and I get up to 4 editables after an upcast - but only if I set the initial item count to something higher than it probably will be (like setting it to 4, even if we have only one editable element).

**Problem**: When I increase the tab count in the widget settings after it has been rendered once, no new editables are recognized as such.

Only if I explicitly fire a initEditable() on each one.

Is there truly no easier way to accomplish what I need and do I really need at least two definitions of my editables (one for init, one for data change)?

Thanks ahead!